# Divider issue on Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css, navigation

Got a slightly annoying issue that I am at my wits end with so looking for some help.

I have made a CodePen for a navigation - http://codepen.io/nickelse/pen/yNwPwv

When you hover over one of the nav links it covers the left divider but shows the right divider, anyone got any suggestions on how I can have the link hover either cover both dividers or sit in the middle of the two?

Cheers,

Nick

```
<div class="navigation cf">
  <div class="menu cf">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Poker Chips</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Poker Chip Sets<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Poker Tables</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Poker Chip Cases</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Poker Playing Cards</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Poker Accessories</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


body {
  background: #272727;
}

/*----- Menu Outline -----*/
.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  background: #454545;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #666;
}

.menu {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

.menu li {
  margin: 0px;
}

.menu a {
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu li:hover > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ddd;
}

.menu .arrow {
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 0%;
}

/*----- Top Level -----*/
.menu > ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/ijNENpN.png) no-repeat left 50%;
}

.menu > ul > li:first-child {
  background: none;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 20px 24px;
  display: block;
}

.menu > ul > li:hover > a{
  background: #666;
}

/*----- Bottom Level -----*/
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.sub-menu {
  width: 280px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity linear 0.2s;
  background: #666;
  text-align: left;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
  padding: 10px 24px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover {
  background: #353535;
}

.navigation .fa.fa-caret-down   {
    margin-left: 6px;   
}


.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " "; /* 1 */
  display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}

/** For IE 6/7 only - Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats. */
.cf {
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: I admit my first thought is don't use an bg image for a divider...your probably better off using a border or pseudo-element.

Comment: @Paulie_D Agreed, the image seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The divider is actually associated with the `li` *next* to the one being hovered so the quick solution is to hide it so:

```
.menu li:hover + li {
  background-image: none;
}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/gpEozx)

Comment: Just lucky I guess, :)

Comment: Appreciate that, been driving me crazy! Thanks! @Paulie_D

Answer (score 2):

Add `padding:3px;` for `li` tag

```
.menu > ul > li {
  padding:3px; //added this
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/ijNENpN.png) no-repeat left 50%;
}
```

[Demo here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbGVqv)

Answer (score 1):

Don't mess around with padding or margin, just define that the `<li>` to the right of the focussed `<li>` should not have the background that displays the border.

Add this bit of CSS code:

```
.menu > ul > li:hover + li {
  background: none;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwxrGx